# How could I make a programming game in UE4 using blueprints, and is it possible?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So, I was interested in starting a project on a 3D game where you hack using the in-game programming language. I'm not a professional, but I do have some experience.

I'm not sure if it's even possible to create a custom coding language using Blueprints. If someone has already created it, or something similar. Please guide me how to make it.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it's possible, but it would be extremely painful even to make something simple. I'd abandon considering blueprints, at-least for writing a parse/interpretation layer.

Comment: Blueprint can be somewhat good for light work string parsing, but if you are trying to implement a parser/interpreter for a language, it's probably not the right fit unless the language is really simple. You might want to look into already-existing interpreted languages you can base yours off of.